Login-DataGatewayServiceAccount gets stuck within a script to query powerbi connections
I have got a powershell script that i will need to run as a service principal because that is how our automation scripts run.
Currently when testing the script, I can run Login-DataGatewayServiceAccount and login interactively when the command Login-DataGatewayServiceAccount is executed from our automation system which uses an applicaiton ID and application secret to authenticate to Azure, it simply gets stuck forever probably due to the login prompt.
Is there an alternative.
I have tried this
Connect-DataGatewayServiceAccount -ApplicationId $zz -ClientSecret $xx  -Tenant $T to no avail.
My script runs the following commands
Get-DataGatewayCluster
Get-DataGatewayClusterDatasource

Try sending a return after login.  You should be seeing a prompt after login.
